# How to change the reducer output file names in a hadoop mr job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers, multipleoutputs

I have a reducer script that need generate a bunch of xml files. I want to set the file name programatically using reducer key. I'm using `MultipleOutputs` to accomplish that as follows.

```
MultipleOutputs mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);
mos.write(new Text(key), new Text(output), key + ".xml");
```

But the output filenames are like `key.xml-r-00000`. How to remove `-r-*` part from the filename so that it will be simply `key.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here -r-0000 shows that it is generated from reducer.We can not change it, If you want your customize file name, write a code after generation of these file to change the file name.